# Force JavaScript update for Friconix

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I embeded [Friconix](https://friconix.com) on my web site (a free icon collection like Font Awesome).
I noticed that when new icons are added in the library, they are not available since the JavaScript file is refreshed in cache.

Is there a way to force the client to refresh JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force browsers to clear their cache. But you can change the path to your script. 
For example, add a GET parameter with version to the path, like this:

```
<script src="/js/main.js?ver=2"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`location.reload` has a parameter of type Boolean that specifies a hard reload. (This isn't too reliable - it depends on the browser and safety/security measures in place):

```
location.reload(true);
```

Alternatively, use a `no-cache` meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```